# Filemaker PHP: Transferring to another folder

Tags: php, filemaker

I have another concern with Filemaker PHP in regards to its path. I am currently accessing a php with Filemaker access to a certain url e.g https://sample.url.org/iWeb/phpfolder/exampleFilemaker.php . It is perfectly working, responded well with no problem at all. Now, I want to transfer this php file to another folder inside phpfolder. For example, I created a folder named transferedFolder. So the path now would be https://sample.url.org/iWeb/phpfolder/transferedFolder/exampleFilemaker.php. The problem is that, there was no response at all after I moved it inside the transferedFolder folder. The same php file, the same code as before yet no response when I transfered it.

What could possibly be the problem on this? I tried to add another php file for testing, this time WITHOUT a filemaker access and it responded well inside the transferedFolder. So I concluded that maybe Filemaker access could possibly be the cause for this or am I missing something? Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Web Publishing with the FileMaker PHP API requires that you have the FileMaker.php file included.

The most common cause for things breaking when you move the files is that you have broken your dependency to FileMaker.php.  If you are on a production environment then you probably have errors turned off which is why you are getting nothing instead of errors listed. Make sure that you have [error reporting turned on](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and then post what errors you are getting.